# Ata2 exception Emask error showing in tty

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm running Arch Linux, the problem is when I turn on my computer and enter the TTY, it's displaying:

```
[ 5159.397489] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[ 5159.397493] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 5159.397495] ata2: SError: { DevExch }
```

Also sometimes it's `ata2 comreset failed`.

However this error is only showing in TTY, I mean there's no such error in gnome-terminal.

I tried to solve it and I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174819), so it says that I can use `e2fsck -c -c` command. But when I try `e2fsck -c -c /dev/sda`, it says the following error:

```
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I also tried the suggestion but the error is the same.

Is this problem about my hard disk? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you mention the BIOS? I only see disk errors here.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Edited, I'm really not good about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the following is **the only error** in this procedure, but it surely needs to be pointed out. You say you used

```
 e2fsck -c -c /dev/sda
```

but the command should have been

```
 e2fsck -c -c /dev/sda1
```

or some such thing. I understand the post you referenced above is unclear on whether you should apply `e2fsck` to a single partition or to the whole disk, and, what is **much** worse, [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck) adds to this confusion by stating

> **Synopsis**
>
> **e2fsck** [ -pacnyrdfkvtDFV ] [ -b superblock ] [ -B blocksize ] [ -l|-L bad_blocks_file ] [ -C fd ] [ -j external-journal ] [ -E extended_options ] device

but (at least) it quickly redresses itself by stating:

> *device* is the device file where the filesystem is stored (e.g. */dev/hdc1*).

It also does make sense: a filesystem does not extend beyond the partition boundary: you can have as many distinct filesystems as you have partitions.

By running `e2fsck` on a partition, you will get more info on the bad blocks, if any. Should you indeed have bad blocks, [this article](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/) explains how to fix them. I'll give you a rundown.

1. First, the filesystem check, for whichever partition

   ```
      sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda1
   ```

   If the filesystem is indeed corrupted you will get an output like:

   ```
      fsck /dev/sda5
      fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
      e2fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
      fsck.ext4: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
      fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

      The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext4
      filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext4
      filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
      is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
      e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
   ```
2. Find where the backup supernodes are kept:

   ```
      mke2fs -n /dev/sda1
   ```

   You will get a long output, at the end of which you will find:

   ```
      Superblock backups stored on blocks:
      32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
   ```
3. It is now time to restore the bad superblock from the backups,

   ```
      e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sda1
   ```

where block_number is the number of the first (sane) backup superblock. You should be done.

Remember: it is not clear at this point which partition has bad superblocks, you will have to run this set of instructions on all partitions until you find the one with the bad superblocks. Though unlikely, there could be several.